# Does God command you to walk in his law

Tags: ezekiel

Does Ezekiel 36:27 “… and I will cause you to walk in my statues and be careful to obey my rules“, imply that God would require individuals with his spirit to follow the law?

Comment: "Cause to" does not mean "require". It means "enable". See Romans ch7 v6

Comment: this question exemplifies that biblical hermeneutics is an art, not a science. Christians will answer differently from Jews. Reform Jews will answer differently from Orthodox ones, and there will also be differences among Christians. While some would close such questions as opinion-based, I think it is important to keep them open so that readers can understand how various hermeneutical methods and theological outlooks can be applied to a given text.

Answer (score 2):

> "And I will put my spirit within you, and cause you to walk in my
> statutes, and ye shall keep my judgments, and do [them]." Ezekiel
> 36:27 K.J.
>
> "And My Spirit I give in your midst, and I have done this, so that in
> My statutes ye walk. And my judgements ye keep, and have done them." Ezekiel 36:27
> YLT

Ezekiel was told by God to say those words to "the house of Israel" that God had scattered amongst the heathen, and brought back to their own land. God had cleansed that polluted nation, which had profaned God's holy name among the nations. He had given them a new heart and a new spirit in their midst.

As the tag is for the Old Testament book of Ezekiel, then the answer clearly shows that the "you" cannot be you, or me, but refers to the earthly nation of Israel in the time of Ezekiel's ministry.

God was commanding the earthly nation of Israel to walk in his statutes, and to keep his righteous judgments. Further, he cleanses them, and renews the heart and spirit of Israel, the nation, in order to do that.

Ezekiel is not addressing individuals as such, but the whole nation of Israel in  his life-time. Of course, Jewish individuals were required to keep all of the Mosaic law given to the nation centuries previously, but it is the nation as a whole that is the "you" in question. God, through Ezekiel, does not address you, or me, in this passage of scripture.

If the question has in mind spiritual Israel, made up of both Jews and Gentiles who belong to Jesus Christ by faith, that is an entirely different question that would require a very different answer. It would have to give New Testament tags and make clear that the question is not about the nation of Israel in Ezekiel's day.

Comment: I think Apostle Paul disagrees with you when he said, “And all these things happened to them (Israel) as examples; and it is written for our (Christians) warning” (1 Cor 10:11). “It was written for us” (1 Cor 9:10). “But it was not written for him only, ……….., but also on account of us, to whom it is about to be counted” (Rom 4:23-24).

Comment: @NepheshRoi  Paul says a massive amount about grace and law, and all Christians ought to know that the O.T. is 'revealed' in the N.T., Paul being an inspired expositor of it. However, the OP asked a hermeneutical question about one O.T. verse and my answer sticks to that. It's no use on this site launching into a different question. Do ask a fresh one on what you mention, which is a topic, and which would need to be posted in Stack Christianity, not Hermeneutics.

Comment: Anne – I respect your point. But if I follow your cue, I would say “you” and “I” can have many ‘other gods’ for us because the first commandment that ‘you shall not have other gods before Me’ is given “to the earthly nation of Israel in the time of Moses’ ministry”. What I would say is that we must not press out too much “hermeneutical” at the expense of proper “exegetical” explanations. Just my personal opinion.

Comment: @NepheshRoi  And I respect your point of view also. It's just that the site controllers do not want personal opinions here, and they require hermeneutic answers on a hermeneutics site - sticking mainly to the text in question! The Christianity Stack site is more suited to what you are hoping for here, with this topic.

Comment: Now Anne has placed me in a dilemma! Should I have “other gods” and be correct in my hermeneutics?! Or should I have only the true living God and be correct in my hermeneutics and exegesis?!

Comment: @NepheshRoi Comments are not for starting debates. A fresh question could be asked by you in Stack Christianity, then I could devote a lot of time to expressing fully the depths of scriptural matters involved. No way can this be tackled in comments. You will not goad me into responding to what is a separate issue outside the scope of hermeneutics. Please go to https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour for clarity on why this site is not like other ones.

Comment: Anne, thanks for the 'exchange'.

Answer (score 1):

In Eze 36, the prophet is predicting a time when God's people would return to Him:

> Eze 36:25-27 - I will also sprinkle clean water on you, and you will
> be clean. I will cleanse you from all your impurities and all your
> idols. I will give you a new heart and put a new spirit within you; **I
> will remove your heart of stone and give you a heart of flesh**. And I
> will put My Spirit within you and cause you to walk in My statutes and
> to carefully observe My ordinances.

This is a direct reference to Jeremiah's earlier statement on the same subject:

> Jer 31:33, 34 - “But this is the covenant I will make with the house
> of Israel after those days, declares the LORD. **I will put My law in
> their minds and inscribe it on their hearts**. And I will be their
> God, and they will be My people. No longer will each man teach his
> neighbor or his brother, saying, ‘Know the LORD,’ because they will
> all know Me, from the least of them to the greatest, declares the
> LORD. For I will forgive their iniquities and will remember their sins
> no more.”

This passage is quoted twice in the NT in Heb 8:8-12, 10:16, 17 as applying to Christians.

Note very carefully this this does NOT mean that keeping the law earns us favor with God; far from it.  Such would be a pointless exercise in futility.  However, God changes the Christian's heart to enable that person to reflect the Character of Jesus.

**It is God who writes the moral law on our hearts!!**

We cannot do that ourselves!

> Eph 2:8-10 - For it is by grace you have been saved through faith, and
> this not from yourselves; it is the gift of God, not by works, so that
> no one can boast. 1For we are God’s workmanship, created in Christ
> Jesus **to do good works, which God prepared in advance as our way of
> life**.

**APPENDIX - NT Statements about the Moral Law**

- Matt 5:17, 18 - “anyone who sets aside one of the least commandments and teaches others accordingly will be called least in the kingdom of heaven”
- Matt 5:19 -  “But it is easier for heaven and earth to pass away than for one jot of the Law to become void.”
- the law is essential because “through the law we become conscious of sin” (Rom 3:21, 7:7, 13)
- “we uphold the law by faith” (Rom 3:31),
- “the law is holy, and the commandment is holy, righteous and good” (Rom 7:12),
- “the law is spiritual” (Rom 7:14),
- “the law is good” (1 Tim 1:8),
- keeping the law is to do right (James 2:8).
- “Do we, then, nullify the law by this faith? Certainly not! Instead, we uphold the law.” (Rom 3:31).
- “What then? Shall we sin because we are not under law, but under grace? Certainly not!” (Rom 6:15);
- “we are now slaves of righteousness” (Rom 6:16)
- “slaves to God” (Rom 6:22);
- “And this is love, that we walk according to His commandments. This is the very commandment you have heard from the beginning, that you must walk in love.” (2 John 6);
- “And having been made perfect, He became the source of eternal salvation to all who obey Him” (Heb 5:9);
- “But the one who looks intently into the perfect law of freedom, and continues to do so—not being a forgetful hearer, but an effective doer—he will be blessed in what he does.” (James 1:25);
- “As you can see, a man is justified by his deeds and not by faith alone.” (James 2:24); etc.

Comment: For an alternate understanding of Ephesians 2:8-10, I highly recommend this study:

https://youtu.be/AIU7MY08-mY

And what is "the moral law"? I hear people use the term but Moses didn't give two laws. Two scriptural terms are "the Royal Law," and "the Law of Christ."

Comment: Instead of using the moral law term, I suggest using alternative ways to distinguish them. Such as spirit or core of the law or works in general, whereas the mosaic covenant law being the shadow and fence in ritual ceremonial form.